# Disable ClipTo mask on Selection

Tags: fabricjs

In Fabric JS how can I disable the ClipTo when the object is selected? We currently have an image that has a rect clipping the image. I want when someone select the image that the mask is removed.

Answer (score 2):

when someone select the image, try this :

```
canvas.clipTo = null;
canvas.renderAll();
```